# MailPress plugin: table inline style tag removed when sending the newsletter

Tags: templates, email, table, css, html-email

I have coded my own MailPress theme for my newsletter using tables and inline styling for good look and feel of my newsletter. I have in the files header.php and footer.php html table code with inline style tags. Something like this:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #ecebea;border-collapse: collapse !important;height: 100% !important;width: 100% !important;">
```

It looks just fine in the email preview, but when sending it and looking at the newsletter from my gmail the tables are without the style tag I wrote. Seems like MailPress is stripping me out all the style="...." stuff?

The above code looks in my email just with this:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
```

"style" and also "id" tags are being completely removed.

Where or how to avoid this happen? Is there some filtering around there where I can place code to allow the style tag in the newsletter content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED, the problem wasn't with wordpress. Just a couple of css and table formatting issues was the cause of gmail displaying wrong my table. In desktops and mobile email clients was looking just good so I was assuming the problem were beyond my html table code. But the own developer of the plugin review it and makes the final touches to my MailPress newsletter template. It looks good everywhere now. The MailPress plugin rocks.